# Why Google Drive app constantly showing popup on startup?

Tags: google-drive-file-stream

I have replaced Google Backup&Sync with Google Drive app and now it is showing popup every time when Windows is started. How to get rid of this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be disabling Google Drive on startup, **but** this comes at the cost of affecting any auto backup you may have set up for *desktop —> cloud*

1. Open task manager *(ctrl+shft+esc)*
2. Click the "Startup" tab
3. Find "Google Drive"
4. Check to see if it is enabled or disabled
5. If disabled, right click anywhere in the entry and then left click "Disable"
6. Restart and check results

Hope that helps!

Comment: It is not solution because it also prevents usage of Google Drive.

Answer (score 0):

Was looking around for this same issue, the best result I've found that works - you actually have to follow the "view more" link vs just closing it. Very annoying and lame, but that seems to be the only thing that keeps it from reappearing.